# ERROR_SMO_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER when I'm trying to Web Deploy

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, deployment, windows-server-2012

When I try to publish project from Visual Studio 2019 to remote IIS server, I'm getting an error:

> "The SQL provider cannot run because of a missing dependency. Please make sure that Microsoft SQL Server Management Objects (Version 10 or higher) is installed.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SMO_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER".

This is the first time I installing software to server, so here is what I did, following instructions on the web:

1. Added features: Windows Deployment Services (with Deployment Server and Transport Server), IIS Management Console, IIS Management Scripts and Tools, Management Service, Logging Tools.
2. Installed SQL Server Management Objects (version 13.0.1601.5), Microsoft Web Deploy 3.6 (because of version 4.0 won't offer me to install IIS Deployment Handler and won't show me Deploy menu in the IIS).
3. Tried to configure Web Deploy Publishing for existing user from Active Directory with defining connection string to SQL server.
4. Allowed users in IIS Manager Permissions.

Some important information:

1. Server is in domain, connection to internet restricted. Application works in intranet.
2. Using Web Platform Installer permitted because of item 1. Any programs should be installed offline only.
3. Server haven't been used for Web Deploy before.
4. Before installing Microsoft Web Deploy 3.6, I was unable to check connection from  Visual Studio and even hadn't current error.

I guess that error happens because of incorrect connnection strings (Enter SQL Server/MySQL connection string to be used for publishing).

Comment: I suggest you could try this solution:Firstly Web Platform Installer to install:
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier Application Framework
SQL Server 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom
SQL Server System CLR Types 11.0, then run this command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\gacutil" /i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130\Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll"`

Comment: It did't work :( But I found other solution - I launched IIS as an administrator and then configured web deploy, so it works.